# org.apache.http.entityutils#toString() is causing java.io.EOFException in case of chunked transfer-encoding when the payload is empty

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

The title of my question very much sums up problem. I will try to provide further details here:

I had enabled the org.apache.http logs and this is the request sent:

```
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Host: <host-address>
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.9 (Java/1.8.0_181)
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:136 - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "GET /data/RestEndPoint('<unique-id>') HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Authorization: Bearer <Bearer-Token>[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: trial-<Host-address>[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.9 (Java/1.8.0_181)[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

I get a valid response from the resource endpoint (in this cases, it is expected to get `HTTP : 404` )
Here is the response from the server/ endpoint

```
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "X-ServiceFabric: ResourceNotFound[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:47532108-1d6f-4e03-9925-5a529abc43fe[\r][\n]"
 
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "0[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.wire:73 - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:122 - http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Content-Encoding: gzip
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << X-ServiceFabric: ResourceNotFound
 DEBUG Test worker org.apache.http.headers:125 - http-outgoing-1 << X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
```

Uptil now everything works fine, but the following block of code is throwing an exception:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

Arrays.stream(response.getAllHeaders())
      .forEach(head -> responseHeaders.put(head.getName(),
                        head.getValue()));

responseEntity = (null != entity)
                ? EntityUtils.toString(entity, HttpConfigConstants.UTF8)
                : null;
```

The line `EntityUtils.toString(entity, HttpConfigConstants.UTF8)` is throwing following exception:

```
 java.io.EOFException
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:268)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:258)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.http.client.entity.GZIPInputStreamFactory.create(GZIPInputStreamFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.initWrapper(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:51)
        at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:69)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:227)
        at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:270)
        at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:290)
```

Isn't the `EntityUtils` class checking for empty stream? Is there a bug in `EntityUtils` or what should I check prior to calling the `EntityUtils.toString(entity, HttpConfigConstants.UTF8)` so that geniune EOF exceptions are not masked and avoid unnecessary EOF exceptions during valid responses?

---

**NOTE:** The same EOFexception would be thrown in case of success http response codes as well that won't have payload for ex: `201 (resource created: POST) 204 (resource updated: PATCH)`

How should I avoid these?

Answer (score 0):

My standing on this is that the server response is invalid. The content-encoding header tells us that the body is gzip encoded. The gzip encoding of zero bytes does not equal zero bytes. Try it by creating an empty file and gzipping it. I think the client works perfectly well.

As a workaround, I suggest removing the Accept-Encoding header from the request. The header is added by Apache HTTP Client by default. You can change that using HttpClientBuilder.disableContentCompression().

Or you override the default Accept-Encoding header with your own using one of the following values:

- identity
- gzip;q=0
- leave the value empty

All should work in theory, but as the server is obviously buggy, only one or none may work.